# How to skip carrierwave uploader callbacks when unarchieving a serialized model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, carrierwave

My problem is that when I destroy some carrierwaved model:

**Attachment.rb**

```
mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader
```

I remove it from the database and serialize it to another table with revisions.

When the user reify the deleted attachment, I need to insert the row back but skipping specific carrierwave callbacks (skip the mount uploder I guess).

The code bellow can do that, but unfortunately it removes all the callbacks from the model and I need them. So I have to skip carrierwave uploader only, otherwise it throws exception with "invalid attachment" when create.

```
  model.class.skip_callbacks do 
    model.save
  end
```

It's possible to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip specific callbacks using [skip_callback](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods/skip_callback), specified with a lambda. Combine that with the specific [callback you are trying to avoid](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb#L28) and you should be able to achieve the control you are looking for.

```
class Attachment
  mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader

  skip_callback :save, :after, :store_attachment!, if: :skip_storage?

  private

  def skip_storage?
    # some skipping logic
  end
end
```